# Doesnot firing OnSelectedIndexChanged event for Dropdownlist control existed in Child Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have parent gridview and child gridview, In child gridview I have one dropdown list, I need to fire the onselectedindexchanged event for that drop down but it is not firring because it is existed in the child gridview. If I place that  dropdown in parent gridview then that selectedindexchanged is firing but I want to place that dropdown in child gridview and need to fire onselectedindexchanged event when user change the dropdown list value . In the below gridview image you can see the Status column in child gridview. It contains dropdown now I want to fire that dropdown seleted index changed event in code behind.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCountry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <img alt="" id="imgsymbol" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvBrokerdetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" OnRowCommand="gvBrokerdetails_RowCommand"
                                            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BrokerName" HeaderText="Name" />
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Include" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Exclude" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDeleteRow" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="25px" CommandName="CrossImageButton" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BrokerId")%>' ImageUrl="~/images/cross-button.png" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryName" HeaderText="Country Name" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But the above is event is not calling. Is there any other process to achieve or I need to specify any new property in the code.

Comment: Are you using `UpdatePannel`?

Comment: Yes I am using panel for child gridview

Comment: Not `Panel`, are you using `UpdatePannel`?

Comment: I am not using Update Panel

Comment: Then your code is correct, is the flow hitting break point in `Page_Load` event? Check your `Page_Load` method, or show in the question.

Comment: Yes while changing the dropdown value it is hitting the page_load event but it is not hitting the ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Are you binding gridview in `Page_Load`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58661/discussion-between-surya-and-bharadwaj).

Answer (score 0):

Find your gridview inside the RowDataBound Event of parent gridview

```
protected void gvCountry_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView mygrid = e.Row.FindControl("gvBrokerdetails") as GridView;
    }
}
```

than handle the event of `mygrid` it is your child grid you can handle any event you want or assign any property to it. an example of `Selected_IndexChanged` is below

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView mygrid = e.Row.FindControl("gvBrokerdetails") as GridView;
        mygrid.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(mygrid_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

void mygrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Write your code here
}
```

Comment: I used the above code Rowdatabound is firing when grid rows are binding to gridview, but when I changing the dropdown value mygrid_SelectedIndexChanged is not firing.

Comment: set autopostback="true" of your both gridviews

Comment: already I placed autopostback for my dropdownlist control, autopostback property not available in gridview control

Comment: ya my mistake i mean for dropdownlist, try to handle selectedindex of dropdown in gridiview_child_rowdatabound.